# Using URL as a parameter in ASP.net web forms

Tags: asp.net, webforms

How could I use MapPageRoute to handle a page request that uses a URL as a parameter?
ex;
http://www.example.com/pageName/http://www.paramter.com/something?v=333

"http://www.paramter.com/something?v=333" is the URL parameter that I want to detect, I've tried `routes.MapPageRoute("", "pageName/{url}", "~/pageName.aspx")`

but the IIS doesn't recognize the path as a valid page.

Answer (score 0):

The slashes are making it think it has multiple parameters.  Change your routeUrl parameter to use a wildcard - that way it'll treat everything thereafter as part of the single parameter.

```
routes.MapPageRoute("", "pageName/{*url}", "~/pageName.aspx")
```